# Android Eclipse - Measuring time accurately

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm creating an app where I need for something to happen if a button isn't pressed within 'x' seconds but if it is pressed then the timer resets and the cycle starts again, but that time frame will most likely be around 0.3 - 0.5 seconds so I can't use a Chronometer right? How should I go about this

Answer (score 0):

A `chonometer` cant solve your issue. Use a `CountDownTimer` instead.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html